# problemas al consumir mi servicio Rest Java

Tags: java

Al ejecutar el método me genera un error 405 me he estado basando en varios ejemplos de internet, cuando comento la variable jsonR y remuevo lo que esta en // 
me genera los valores pero en null ya que no estoy mandando el cuerpo del json he estado buscando mas ejemplos en internet pero viéndolos no encuentro algun error ¿alguien que me pueda brindar su ayuda?

```
public void ms (String name,String psw)  {
        try {
            String jsonR = "[{\"usr\":\""+name+"\", \"pswd\":\""+psw+"\"}]";

            URL url = new URL("Mi URL" + name);
            HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
            conn.setRequestProperty("Accept","application/json");
            //
            conn.setDoOutput(true);
            OutputStream os = conn.getOutputStream();
            os.write(jsonR.getBytes());
            os.flush();
            os.close();
            int responseCode = conn.getResponseCode();
            System.out.println("Response Code :  " + responseCode);
            System.out.println("Response Message : " + conn.getResponseMessage());
            //
            if(conn.getResponseCode()==200){
                BufferedReader br= new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader((conn.getInputStream())));
                String output;
                System.out.println("output");

                while((output = br.readLine()) != null){
                    System.out.println(output);

                    try {
                        JSONObject json = new JSONObject(output);
                        String Status = json.getString("Status");

                        System.out.println(Status);
                    }catch (Exception E){System.out.println("error"+E.getMessage());}
                }
                conn.disconnect();
            }
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```